# multiple databricks notebooks scheduling via one job using common parameter

Tags: databricks

I have a practical use case​. three notebooks (pyspark)  all have on​e common parameter.

need  to schedule all three notebooks in a sequence.

is  there any way to run them by setting one parameter value,  as they are same in all?

please suggest the best way to do it.

Comment: Create a master notebook, and pass the corresponding parameter to these notebooks. Essentially, these notebooks would act as child notebooks. You can use `dbutils.notebook.run(path = <Notebook Path>, timeout_seconds= <timeout_seconds>, arguments = <parameter to be passed>)` to call your child notebook.

Comment: Thanks, so how do i use parameter in child notebook, i.e if i have a SQL query in child do i need to pass parameter from widget like this :   {{ arg1 }}  ?

Comment: See this [official documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#widgets-in-sql) from databricks